# エスケープシーケンスの文字をブラウザに表示したいです。

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Springbootのコントローラーから以下で変換した値をHTML5で表示しようとしています。

```
String text = "\100です。"
String disp = text.replaceAll("\\\\", "&yen;");
```

→ `"&yen;100です。"`

これをHTML5側で表示したいのですが、変化しません…。
そのまま「`&yen;100です。`」と表示されてしまいます。

```
<div class="start-message">
    <span th:id="disp" th:text="${disp}"></span>
</div>
```

なにか良い方法はないでしょうか。

Comment: このように\の後に数字がありますと、文字コードを8進数で示したことになります。`\100`という文字列リテラルはANSIやUTF-8では「@」を意味します。`"\100です。"`は`"@です。"`となります。タイポでしたら修正しておいて下さい。

Comment: テンプレートエンジンには Thymeleaf を使用しているという事でよろしいでしょうか。タグに入れましたので、間違っていたら修正して下さい。

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot のことはさっぱり知りませんが、おそらく変数 `text` も `disp` も HTML のソースではなく、単なる文字列です。一般の文字列中で HTML の実体参照 `&yen;` に特別な意味はなく、HTML を生成するときに `&amp;yen;` のようにエスケープされているのだと思われます。

実体参照を使わずに、文字 U+00A5 を直接入れればよいと思われます。

```
String disp = text.replaceAll("\\\\", "\u00A5");
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございますString disp = text.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\xA5");としてみたのですが、xA5と表示されてしまいました。。もう頭がこんがらかってます

Comment: \\xA5 ではなく \xA5 です。

Comment: すみません、「\xA5 」を指定すると「エスケープ・シーケンスが無効です」と怒られてしまうため変更していました…

Comment: おおっとごめんなさい、\x は Java にはないのでしたね。\u00A5 としてください。回答も更新しておきます。

Comment: ソースコード（の文字リテラル）に「¥」を直接に記述すると何か問題があるのでしょうか。

Comment: 非ASCII文字をソースコードに入れると問題が起きがちなので、お勧めしません。U+005C と見た目が変わらないフォントもありますし。

Comment: なるほど、そうなんですか。そういうフォントがあるとするとHTMLに含めるのも注意が必要ですね。

Answer (score 1):

「¥」でしたらHTMLにおいて特別な意味がないと思いますので、int32_tさんの回答のように、ただそのまま含めればよいと思います。

HTMLで意味を持つ記号や実体参照をエスケープさせずにそのままHTML中に挿入したいのでしたら、各テンプレートごとに方法が用意されていますから、それを使う事になります。

> ThymeleafでXHTMLタグをエスケープせずに表示したいのであれば、違う属性を使用しなければなりません: th:utext (“unescaped text”用):
>   [エスケープなしのテキスト](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf_ja.html#%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%97%E3%81%AE%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88)